# how to join these individual queries into a single query

Tags: mysql, join

I have two individual queries, which I have to join them into single query.

1st query:

I have a parameter called name in a request. When I give that name, it should determine its id. Example: If I give VS-ABC in a request it should determine it's id=1.

stu_details table

```
[{id:1,name:"VS-ABC"]} -- sample input record to refer

select * from stu_details where name="VS-ABC"
```

2nd query:

```
select * from PR
where pr_id in (select pr_id from PRS where id =1)
```

Here id =1 and I am giving it manually, but I wanted these queries to run in a single shot and dynamically. Whenever I pass a request "name" parameter then it should determine that id and pass in the second query inside IN query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT [DISTINCT] pr.* 
FROM pr
JOIN prs ON pr.pr_id = prs.pr_id
JOIN stu_details ON stu_details.id = prs.id
WHERE stu_details.name = 'VS-ABC';
```

Whether DISTINCT is needed or not depends on the data.

PS. Do not use double quote chars `"` for literals quoting, you must use single quote chars `'` for this purposes.

Comment: Now in where condition I am giving actual value, but I have to get input "name" column and assign it to name, How I can do that?